# Arduino Robot Chasis

Tags: arduino-nano, robotics

I am looking into building a robot with my Arduino Nano but I don't want to shell out more then 50 bucks. Does anyone have any suggestions for a four wheel robot chassis at this price that I could use to make my robot mobile?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not give out shopping advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty of [options on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Hot-sale-4WD-Robot-Smart-Car-Chassis-with-Speed-Encoder-DC-3V5V6V-for-Arduin-EEW-/291423639383?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item43da33d757), you will have to add a DC motor [driver](http://www.ebay.com/itm/L9110S-H-bridge-Stepper-Motor-Dual-DC-motor-Driver-Controller-Board-New-GA-/181650502852?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&hash=item2a4b36b4c4) and optionally, sensors, but these are a good starting point.

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'good'. The ones I have seen were not machined symmetrically, wheels rubbed the chassis, wires broke off the motor if you breathed on them. Just beware, cheap stuff is usually cheap stuff. Learning to properly cut and drill a $.50 piece of plywood is an as valuable skill as blinking an LED, maybe more.

Comment: I can only speak for my experience, which has been quite good so far.
A DIY approach works too, but generates lots of overhead.
Tools required to do a proper job usually do not come cheap.

Comment: The ones that are really cheap are from "Emgreat" ... simple and "good enough".  I'd suggest get a low end and play ... the model I bought can be seen here:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Motor-New-Smart-Robot-Car-Chassis-Kit-Speed-Encoder-Battery-Box-For-Arduino-/361060892190?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5410e7fe1e